# Сравнение двух одинаковых одномерных масссивов в JS, один из которых периодически меняет свое содержимое

Tags: javascript, массивы

есть пустяковый вопрос. Как  в JS сравнить два массива? Причем, не нужно выяснять, какие именно из элементов не совпадают. Дополнительного массива различающихся данных тоже создавать не надо. Просто сравнить одинаковые ли они или нет, если различаются, к примеру, делаем выбор тот или иной выбор через конструкцию  `switch / case`  ну или еще как-то. Так же есть еще условие, массив  `TempbinArray6` будет постоянно меняться, и после каждого изменения необходимо делать сравнение.

```
var TempbinArray6 = Array( 0, 1, 1 );
var TempbinArray = Array( 1, 0, 0, );
```

Comment: не равенство массивов, это когда `a[i] != b[i]`? или когда присутствуют различные элементы?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Массивы могут содержать только 0 и 1. Можно ли сравнить два массива не обращаясь к каждому их элементу в отдельности?

Comment: ну раз у вас такой узкоспециализированный массив и такая ускоспециализированная задача - то храните данные в строке и сравнивайте сразу строки, а до буквы строки вы и так как в массиве дотянуться если надо сможете

Comment: Ну вот конкретну эту задачу можно решить как `TempbinArray6.join() === TempbinArray.join()`. Вроде работает.

Comment: Чем вам не нравится сравнивать два массива по элементам?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, а у автора вероятно огромный многомегабайтовый буффер, разбитый на биты. В таком случае, можно сравнивать хэши буфферов, если они сходятся, то можно считать, что буфферы эквивалентны. [MD5](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html) или [SHA](https://javascript.ru/php/sha1).

Comment: Так хеш еще надо вычислить. Не уверен, что создание хеша быстрее по-элементного обхода @DiD

Comment: Вопрос только в ценности операция сравнения. Во время обхода нужно её выполнять, и иногда подсчёт контрольной суммы при обходе и одно сравнение дешевле N сравнений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сравнить два массива надо: убедиться что они одного размера, затем убедиться что по всем индексам имеет одинаковые элементы.

```js
const [a, b, c] = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3]
];
// сравниваем a и b
console.log(a.length == b.length && a.every((v, i) => b[i] == v)) // false
// сравниваем a и с
console.log(a.length == c.length && a.every((v, i) => c[i] == v)) // true
```

Comment: А можно вместо `every` сделать `some` с отрицанием. Будет производительней!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, не верю, первый false в every так же досрочно прекращает вычисления, как и первый true в some... По крайней мере, ничто не мешало сделать именно так)

Comment: DiD, не могли бы вы по-подробнее расписать что и как в вашем алгоритме происходит. Я еще плохо понимаю некоторые вещи.

Comment: @stepUP, без проблем. первые 5 строк оператора const - это присваивание трем константам значений: a=[1,2,3], b=[4,5,6], c=[1,2,3]. Потом идёт два вызова метода console.log(), который выводит в консоль результат выражения, переданного в функцию аргументами. В данном случае это один аргумент - результат сравнения двух массивов (сначала **a** и **b**, потом **a** и **с**). Само выражение сравнения состоит из двух сравнений, соединенных унарным **и** &&: сначала сравниваем длины массивов, потом, если они равны - сравниваем каждый элемент массивов.

Comment: @stepUP, Функция-метод Array.prototype.every() принимает первым параметром функцию сравнения двух элементов. Если все элементы равны, every() будет выполнять переданную функцию столько раз, сколько элементов в массиве. Если элементы не равны, every() остановит выполнение, когда выполнение функции в аргументе возвратит отрицательный результат.

Comment: @step Сама функция в аргументе должна работать так: в функцию передаются три параметра (мы читаем только первые два): 1) значение текущего элемента, 2) индекс текущего элемента, 3) сам массив, метод которого вызван (в данном случае - а), Функция должна возвратить true если утверждение верное или false в противном случае. В качестве выражения внутри функции мы сравниваем **i-тый** элемент массива **b** со значением текущего элемента **v**.

Comment: @step чтобы понять как работает every(), можно выпонить вот такой код: ['a','b','c'].every( (v,i) => { console.log( 'array[' + i + '] = ' + v ); return true; });

Comment: @step потом можно выполнить вот такой код:
[1,0,1].every((v,i)=>{ console.log( 'array[' + i + '] = ' + v ); return v == 1; }); код проверяет чтобы каждый элемент был равен единице. Функция выполнится всего два раза, так как есть элемент, равный нолю.

Comment: @step А выполнив вот такой код: Array.prototype.equals = function equals(array){ return this.length == array.length && this.every((v,i)=>array[i]==v); };
можно будет сравнивать два массива вот так: [1,0,1].equals([1,0,1]);  Проверьте: console.log( [1,0,1].equals([1,0,1]) ); console.log( [1,0,1].equals([0,1,0]) );

Comment: Благодарю. Теперь все понятно. Очень помогло.

Comment: Странное дело. Перегрузил страницу браузера, в консоли по новой ввел строчку console.log( [1,0,1].equals([1,0,1]) ); - не работает. Выдает ошибку  Uncaught TypeError: [1, 0, 1].equals is not a function. Хотя до этого возвращало результат true.

Comment: @stepUP Потому что отсутствует код? Array.prototype.equals = function equals(array){ return this.length == array.length && this.every((v,i)=>array[i]==v); }; функцию надо определить перед тем, как использовать.

Comment: @stepUP Также рекомендовал бы добавить туда проверку типа: Array.prototype.equals = function equals(array){ return Array.isArray(array) &&  this.length == array.length && this.every((v,i)=>array[i]==v); } чтобы всегда выдавало false если переданно, например, число или строка