# Node-Red и .equals is not a function или как сравнить два массива

Tags: javascript

Ткните носом пожалуйста. Что не так?
В Node Red пишу функцию для сравнения двух массивов. Первый `bin` ко мне прилетает, я его преобразую `TempbinArray`, беру из него то, что мне надо и хочу сравнить с одним из шаблонов `TempbinArray1`. Не пойму, почему оператор `.equals` не работает. Появляется ошибка `TypeError: TempbinArray.equals is not a function`. Хотя в консоле вот  это работало:  console.log( [1,0,1].equals([1,0,1]) );

Мой код

```js
var msg1 = {
  payload: ""
};

var TempbinArray1 = [0, 0, 0]; // Период выхода на всязь - 5 мин
var TempbinArray2 = [1, 0, 0]; // Период выхода на всязь - 15 мин
var TempbinArray3 = [0, 1, 0]; // Период выхода на всязь - 30 мин
var TempbinArray4 = [1, 1, 0]; // Период выхода на всязь - 1 час
var TempbinArray5 = [0, 0, 1]; // Период выхода на всязь - 6 часов
var TempbinArray6 = [1, 0, 1]; // Период выхода на всязь - 12 часа  
var TempbinArray7 = [0, 1, 1]; // Период выхода на всязь - 24 часа
var res = 0;

var bin = ("00000000" + (parseInt(msg.payload, 16)).toString(2)).substr(-8);
//var bin = "10000100";

binArray = Array.from(bin); //делаем новый массив


if (binArray[0] == 0) {

  msg1.payload = "OTTA";
} else msg1.payload = "ABP";

var TempbinArray = binArray.slice(2, 5); // Выбираем из массива значения соответствующие времени выхода устройства на связь

// как я думаю проблема строчкой ниже
if (TempbinArray.equals([0, 1, 0])) {
  msg2.payload = "5 мин";

} else {
  msg2.payload = "не сконфигурировано";

}


return [msg1, msg2, msg3, msg4, msg5, msg6, msg7];
```

Comment: в нативном js вроде нет Array.equals

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос разрешился. Дело было в определении функции перед ее использованием

```
Array.prototype.equals = function equals(array){ return this.length == array.length && this.every((v,i)=>array[i]==v); };
```

Большое спасибо DiD за подсказку. Ссылка на [пост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1190721/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-js-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA/1190813?noredirect=1#comment2077157_1190813). Определение вставил перед используемой функцией.